# Is this SEO Keyword Stuffing?

Tags: seo, keywords

Just wondering if you can tell me if this is keyword stuffing:

```
<a title="purchase glasses" href=""><img alt="purchase glasses" title="purchase glasses" /><a>
<a title="purchase socks" href=""><img alt="purchase socks" title="purchase socks" /><a>
```

So I thought the following could be penalized:

- 'purchase' is included with each product title & alt
- the  title is the same as the  title and alt

Any ideas?

If this is safe could you please give an example of keyword stuffing. Thanks!

Comment: Who wants to penalize you?

Comment: Google's algorithm takes a lot of variables into consideration and I imagine that it will penalize the page ranking from any obvious black hat SEO techniques, such as keyword stuffing.

Comment: Wow. You've already missed the point. You're so concerned about search engines you're ruining your users' experience on your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont be a Keyword stuffing, since you are not repeating. Suppose if you would have used as the following, then it would have been keyword stuffing:

```
<a title="purchase glasses, Purchase glass" href=""><img alt="purchase glasses purchase" title="purchase glasses purchase" /><a>
```

It is advisable that you don't repeat the same word more than 2 times. Google doesn't recommend that  . What you have done is reasonable.

Comment: Where did the number 2 come from? That's oddly specific without an actual source being provided.

Answer (score 2):

This is not keyword stuffing per se, but there is a point where adding keywords becomes superfluous. Using the same text for two titles and an alt tag isn't going to make the page rank any higher for that term than just using one.

You should certainly remove one of the title attributes: using one on the image an another on the link that contains it makes no sense.

Furthermore, you are using the alt attribute incorrectly - alt text should describe the content of the image. The title (on either the image OR link) would describe the action or the page being linked to.